# The relationship between JAVA and html

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Is JAVA compatible with html and js? Can we work together other than jsp???

To link the WEKA function.We implemented the java code using jar, and we need the html and js links for visualization. Is there any other method of linkage besides jsp?

Comment: So far what I have found is Java and JavaScript don't have any "compatibility" at all! _(not more than Java and any other programming language)_.  I cannot "pass" object references between the two (java.rmi doesn't work!).  If you use JSON, they both can communicate, but not in  a way different than Java and _any other programming language_.  A **JavaScript library** that is capable of reading/writing **Serialized Java Objects** and/or using the methods that those objects have **inside JavaScript** would be great...  Right now Java and JavaScript have **AJAX, JSON, HTML** - like everybody else

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of working with Web tech and Java. JSP is an old-school means of generating a Web page using Java code and supplying it to a browser. This requires an application server capable of handling HTTP and JSP. Another approach is to create an independent Web page and to communicate with a server that is running Java. The simplest approach is, again, to use an application server that supports HTTP.

Reading between the lines of your question, I think the various solutions will require more effort than you were hoping.